# dateFromString returning wrongDate

Tags: iphone

I am converting an NSString like @"12:25 AM May 27 2011" into NSDate.But as I convert it using the following code

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a MMM dd YYYY"];
NSDate *date = [[dateFormatter dateFromString:@"12:25 AM May 27 2011"] copy];
[dateFormatter release];
```

I get the wrong Date as 2010-12-25 19:25:00 +0000

Can anyone please help me around here

Comment: it depends upon timezone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a wrong date, the time is displayed [GMT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time) hance (+0000) if you set the correct timezone very thing will be oke.

Comment: Yes, we have you use a NSDateFormatter to create a string from date it will use your phone's time zone en calculate the correct time with the offset of the current time zone.